# How to Hibernate Batch Insert with real time data? Use @Transactional or not?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional

I am trying to perform batch inserts with data that is currently being inserted to DB one statement per transaction. Transaction code statement looks similar to below. Currently, **addHolding()** method is being called for each quote that comes in from an external feed, and each of these quote updates happens about 150 times per second.

```
public class HoldingServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private HoldingDAO holdingDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void addHolding(Quote quote) {
        Holding holding = transformQuote(quote);
        holdingDao.addHolding(holding);
    }

}
```

And DAO is getting current session from Hibernate `SessionFactory` and calling save on object.

```
public class HoldingDAOImpl {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addHolding(Holding holding) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(holding);
    }

}
```

I have looked at [Hibernate batching documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html), but it is not clear from document how I would organize code for batch inserting in this case, since I don't have the full list of data at hand, but rather am waiting for it to stream.

Does merely setting Hibernate batching properties in properties file (e.g. `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20`) "magically" batch insert these? Or will I need to, say, capture each quote update in a synchronized list, and then insert list load and clear list when batch size limit reached?

Also, the whole purpose of implementing batching is to see if performance improves. If there is better way to handle inserts in this scenario, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the property hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20 is an indication for the hibernate to Flush the objects after 20. In your case hibernate automatically calls sessionfactory.flush() after 20 records saved.

When u call a sessionFactory.save(), the insert command is only fired to in-memory hibernate cache. Only once the Flush is called hibernate synchronizes these changes with the Database. Hence setting hibernate batch size is enough to do batch inserts. Fine tune the Batch size according to your needs.

Also make sure your transactions are handled properly. If you commit a transaction also forces hibernate to flush the session.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I believe in code I posted above, transaction commit (and therefore flush) is automatically happening with each insert, since service method is using Transactional annotation. Is this correct assumption? If so, is there a clean way, with Transactional tag or interceptors, to perform batch commit after 25 entries? I'd rather not keep track of inserts already made in code, as it would lead to synchronization mess.

Comment: Please specify how your service method is called. If its called from any other bean directly (for ex from a controller) then this could be the right way to use Transactional annotation. If you are calling the service method inside a loop or something to save multiple records at once then the Transactional annotation should be moved to the calling method. Make Sure service method is not completed and hence not committed until no of batch update size insert happens.

Comment: The service method is called from method in another bean, which essentially just puts data into its own hashmap, then makes addHolding service call. This outer method is called ~150 times per second, from a non-bean class, each time event comes from external feed.

Comment: Then move the Transactional to the outer method. make sure the multiple calls to the service method happens inside transaction context rather than having transactioncontext for each call. So Hibernate can commit only after multiple inserts happens. Since the batch size is set and the transaction context is outside only after 20 inserts hibernate syncs these changes with the database.

Comment: Hmm...ok, I'll see if I can make some intermediate class that batches these up and sends to batch insert transactional service method. Thanks for all the help, bud :)